# Why method of AppHeader component is not triggered on emit?

Tags: laravel-livewire

In Laravel 8, livewire2 I make a header component , which I call in
resources/views/layouts/frontpage.blade.php :

```
</head>

<body class="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
<header>
    @livewire('app-header', ['layout'=>'frontend'])
</header>

<main class="frontend_page_container_wrapper z-20 ">
    {{ $slot }}
</main>

<footer class="bg-green" style="height: 138px !important;">
    @livewire('frontend-footer')
</footer>

@stack('modals')

@livewireScripts
</body>

</html>
```

To update current info in header when new page is opened in any component I call event of AppHeader component.
Like in app/Http/Livewire/Hostel/HostelsHomepageSpotlight.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Hostel;

...
use Livewire\Component;

class HostelsHomepageSpotlight extends Component
{
    
    ...
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.hostel.hostels-homepage-spotlight', [
        ])->layout('layouts.frontpage');
    } // public function render()
    
    public function mount()
    {
        
        $this->hostelsDataRows = Hostel
            ::getByStatus('A')
            ...
            ->paginate($hostels_per_page);
            ...
        
        \Log::info(  varDump(-1, ' -1 HostelsHomepageSpotlight before setCurrentPageProperties::') );
//        $this->emitUp('setCurrentPageProperties', [  // IF TO UNCOMMENT THIS LINE - IT DOES NOT WORK
        $this->emitTo('AppHeaderAppHeader','setCurrentPageProperties', [
            'layout'                => "frontend",
            'icon'                  => 'hostel',
            'additive_class'        => '',
            'title'                 => 'Spotlight hostels',
            'trigger_js_event'      => true,
            'template_container_id' => "hostels_homepage_spotlight_page_container"
        ]);
        
    } // public function mount()
    ...
```

and in app/Http/Livewire/AppHeader.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class AppHeader extends Component
{
    ...
    protected $listeners = ['setCurrentPageProperties' => 'setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback'];
    public function render()
    {    
        return view('livewire.app-header',  [])
            ->layout('layouts.') ;//. $this->layout;
    }
    
    public function mount(
        ...
    ) {
        ...
    }
    
    
    public function setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback($data)
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($data, 'INSIDE  -1  setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback $data::'));
        if ( ! empty($data['layout'])) {
            $this->layout = $data['layout'];
        }
        ...
    } // public function setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback($data)
    
}
```

When I open page with HostelsHomepageSpotlight.php component
I see degugging line

```
-1 HostelsHomepageSpotlight before setCurrentPageProperties
```

but not

```
INSIDE  -1  setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback
```

as setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback method of HostelsHomepageSpotlight.php is not triggered.

How can it be fixed?

**MODIFIED BLOCK :**

1. I had misspelling in name of target component. It is “AppHeader”, so fixing  :

```
            $this->emitTo('AppHeader','setCurrentPageProperties', [
```

this event is not triggered in app/Http/Livewire/AppHeader.php, with declared :

```
    class AppHeader extends Component
    {  
        ...
        protected $listeners = ['setCurrentPageProperties' => 'setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback'];
        ...
        public function setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback($data)
        {
            \Log::info(varDump($data, 'INSIDE  -1  setCurrentPagePropertiesCallback $data::'));
        ...
        }
    }
```

I also tried :

```
            $this->emit('setCurrentPageProperties', [
```

But it does not work anyway...

2. In AppHeader Component resources/views/livewire/app-header.blade.php I added calling method of AppHeader Component  as :

```
    <a  wire:click="appHeaderClickTest"  class=" block text-sm px-2 py-4 hover:bg-green-500 transition duration-300 ">
       Test2
    </a>
```

with defintion in app/Http/Livewire/AppHeader.php :

```
    public function appHeaderClickTest() {
        \Log::info(  varDump(-12, ' -12 appHeaderClickTest::') );
    }
```

and clicking on "Test2" button I see message in log file.
So I check that I put valid AppHeader Component and it works ok when I click "Test2" button

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:**
I created new livewire app EventsTest

with 4 components:

```
php artisan make:livewire Home
php artisan make:livewire hostel/HostelsHomepageSpotlight
php artisan make:livewire AppHeader
php artisan make:livewire hostel/HostelViewPage
```

and I placed HostelsHomepageSpotlight on home page.
In my app just 2 links and AppHeader at header of resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
I emit event setCurrentPageProperties but it is not triggered in AppHeader (I have default title and no logs rows)

I uploaded it on https://github.com/sergeynilov/EventsTest
Could you please to look at it?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 3:**

It works (I see valid title text) with setting

from root div of HostelsHomepageSpotlight template, but as in 
mount() method of HostelsHomepageSpotlight I read all data from db which I show on HostelsHomepageSpotlight page 
I see flashing data on my page andnext  all data has dissapeared. It looks like :

- 1. mount() method read all data on my of HostelsHomepageSpotlight
     page 2) emitHeaderToComponent is called from template 3) method
     emitHeaderToComponent inside of component is run and emiting
     setCurrentPageProperties from header component 4) in heade component
     title of header is assigned and I see it in header of my app

But in one of 2-4 steps data I read on step 1 is cleared... Why and how can it be fixed?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 4 :**

In component HostelsHomepageSpotlight.php I declared array and fill it in mount method :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Hostel;

use Livewire\Component;

class HostelsHomepageSpotlight extends Component
{
    private $hostelsDataRows = [];

    public function render()
    {
        \Log::info('-1 HostelsHomepageSpotlight ::' . print_r(-1, true));


        return view('livewire.hostel.hostels-homepage-spotlight', [
            'hostelsDataRows' => $this->hostelsDataRows,

        ]);
    }

    public function mount()
    {
        \Log::info('-1 HostelsHomepageSpotlight MOUNT -99::' . print_r(-99, true));

        $this->hostelsDataRows = [
            ['id' => 1, 'label 1'],
            ['id' => 2, 'label 2'],
        ];
    }


    public function emitHeaderToComponent()
    {

/*        $this->hostelsDataRows = [
            ['id' => 5, 'label 5'],
            ['id' => 6, 'label 6'],
        ];*/
        $this->emit('setCurrentPageProperties', [
            'title' => 'Cal from ' . __CLASS__,
        ]);
    }
}
```

and showing content of hostelsDataRows in resources/views/livewire/hostel/hostels-homepage-spotlight.blade.php
I see data flashing and disseapering from the screen.

I looks like that emitHeaderToComponent triggered after mount and clears content of all variable how they are declared
in the component.

If to uncomment filling of hostelsDataRows in emitHeaderToComponent - these data are visible on the screen.
I think that could be decision of the issue(loading of all component data in  wire:init=""), but not sure is
it good decision? If this behaviour/feature described in docs?

Thanks!

Comment: please take a look at MODIFIED BLOCK

Comment: Looking at the code of resources/views/layouts/frontpage.blade.php again, I see that
 @livewire('app-header', is called in block  which is out of {{ $slot }}. Can it be the issue 
 and how can it be fixed then ?

Comment: please take a look at MODIFIED BLOCK  # 2

Comment: I think if you make a full page refresh you will loose the state. And that's the reason the title property is not updated in think

Comment: You can use ```wire:init```

Comment: Which practical decision can be here ?
Maybe my app structure is wrong for livewirw app?
Can it be in some other way?

Comment: Could you pleasew explain with use of wire:init ?

Comment: check the answer

Comment: what do you mean step 1 data is cleared

Comment: please provide github repo with the issue

Comment: i am not sure what is the issue here. i have already fixed it

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 4 . Also I updated the git

Comment: You can't use event and listeners while full page relod.

Comment: wire:init is the workaround

Comment: Can be any suitable decison here? I hope it is clear what I want...
Looking some Livewire examples I see small pieces of code, but not common layout.
I think I can on any component inited to call dispatchBrowserEvent and trigger common JS function of header...
But I tried to avoid using JS when it is possible...

Comment: Only way that i am seeing to achive your requirements is you need call the header component on each page and set the value from there by passing the value directly to header component

Comment: you are ok with that. I will make the changes

Answer (score 1):

When the whole page refreshes you will lose the state. So that's why **events** and **listeners** are not working

So as I suggested you can use `wire:init` as workaround.

Add the below methods to both `HostelsHomepageSpotlight` and `HostelViewPage` component.

```
public function emitHeaderToComponent()
{
    $this->emit('setCurrentPageProperties', [
        'title' => 'Cal from ' . __CLASS__,
    ]);
}
```

Now open the view for the respective components `hostels-homepage-spotlight` and `hostel-view-page` and add the following

```
<div wire:init="emitHeaderToComponent">
Your  componenet based other stuff
</div>
```

Now try clicking the link.

I will make a fork the repo and make changes and provide you a link so that it will be more clear

Submitted PR [here](https://github.com/sergeynilov/EventsTest/pull/1)

Comment: Thanks!. Please take a look at MODIFIED BLOCK # 2